# Adding DLL to the resources

Tags: c#, dll, resources, interop

My app is using a win32 DLL (implemented with `C language`). It is necessary for the app to to work. Well, I want to merge the DLL with the exe, by adding the DLL to the exe resources. Can I add it as binary stream? If not, how can I merge the DLL with the app?

Comment: you want to merge it into the EXE file ? and/or you want to use it without extracting it from the EXE ?

Comment: @Yahia I want to run program without need the DLL to be near. I want the dll to be in the exe itself. I prefer using without extracting.

Comment: IF the DLL is native then you need to extract it to a file (for example on the start of the EXE) - there is NO documented/supported way for native DLLS to be used the way you describe... IF the DLL were a .NET DLL then this would be possible/supported...

Comment: @Mr.DDD if 32bit support is enough -> http://upx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Yahia Pleae put your comment as an answer

Comment: @L.B UPX is a compressor for EXE. That doesn't make sence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments above:

IF the DLL is native then you need to extract it to a file (for example on the start of the EXE) - there is NO documented/supported way for native DLLs to be used the way you describe...

IF the DLL were a .NET DLL then this would be possible/supported (by loading it as an Assembly via a memory/Resource stream or byte[])...

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.dottodotnet.com/2010/10/read-embedded-resource-text-file-in-c.html
and [Embedded Binary Resources - how can I enumerate the image files embedded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788504/embedded-binary-resources-how-can-i-enumerate-the-image-files-embedded) You can add it as binary stream and as as such.

Then you have to save it to the file and late bind it as explained in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dyninvok.aspx

Comment: So how to invoke function after loading the library?

Comment: The codeproject link given above does show you how to call a method. Is your requirement anything different? You have to do dynamic invocation.