# Building custom PDF browser cum viewer : Bundle PDFs inside exe

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, encryption

I want to build an application to view a bunch of PDF files. It will have some tree to browse contents and I will use some of the freely available PDF viewer libraries into my application.
But, I want to bundle those PDFs inside my application's exe(and encrypt them if possible). The reason being I don't want the users to be able to save the files. I want them to read the files only.
Is this possible?

PS: I am a newbie when it comes to .net development. So, feel free to suggest any alternatives which will achieve my purpose.

If possible, also suggest a good free PDF viewer library which only allows read and not save/print.

Comment: As a free lib use itextsharp.

Comment: Just so you know, you can do this just to raise the bar for how difficult it is to copy your PDFs.  However, since the PDF needs to be decrypted on the client machine in order to view it, there is no foolproof way to prevent them from copying and distributing the data.

Comment: @kostas ch. iTextSharp can not render PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to embed a resource in your EXE that happens to be an encrypted PDF. You may encrypt them offline, and then add them as a file to your Visual Studio project. Set the 'build action' property to embedded resource.

This one answers how to enumerate the embedded resources:
[Embedded Binary Resources - how can I enumerate the image files embedded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788504/embedded-binary-resources-how-can-i-enumerate-the-image-files-embedded)

Once you have the resource, you must decrypt and pass the data to the PDF viewer you picked.

This one explains how to encrypt and decrypt .NET using the AES symmetric algorithm:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

After decrypting, pass the data to your PDF viewer. If you search for this on SO you will find plenty.

Comment: A small query, can resources embedded in such a way be extracted using something like resource hacker? If yes, any way I can prevent it?

Comment: No, but after they have extracted the resource it is encrypted. Since you will be decrypting from your own code, it is not entirely safe though.

Comment: I am not looking for some state of the art security....just enough secure to prevent normal people from subverting my measures...btw, when I decrypt, it will be temporarily stored on local disk right? So, users can copy it from there?

Comment: No, you can decrypt from and to memory. If you take a look at the provided link you will see how.